# 2002 Citroen Saxo - Clicking / tapping noise from inlet manifold

Tags: fuel-system, noise, citroen

I have a clicking / tapping noise coming from the inlet manifold on my 2002 Citroen Saxo VTR (1.6 8v)

I have manually adjusted the valve clearances (see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qL2wWCB-6mQ) to hear what the engine sounded like before the valve clearance adjustment) however there is a clicking noise which seems to be coming from the inlet manifold from behind the engine.

You can hear the clicking noise in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HLU6CcvD7a4). When holding the idle actuator valve I believe I can feel it moving/vibrating at the same speed as the clicking sound.

I unplugged the idle actuator valve and ran the car for a few seconds however there was still the clicking noise. I have read some posts on Saxo forums which mention a similar sound, saying it could be the injectors.

Comment: sounds like a exhaust leak ,also may have lifter or valve guide problems....did you do a compression check?

Comment: Sounds like you are hearing the injectors - which is NORMAL

Answer (score 0):

That could be injector box i.if it was lifter it would get louder more gas you give it.valve would have more solid tap .look for a sensor around middle of motor see if it has the one controls fast idle . sounds like that silonode for fast idle on cold start might be running all time .Not for certain but I've heard that before ? hope you find it ?good luck .

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you pass a compression test, two cylinders may be the culprit. If they are sharing combustion it will sound a lot like a valve ticking but really its a small amount of the explosion leaking into the adjacent cylinder. They should hold the compression steady, if one of the cylinders doesnt hold steady thats an issue, and that will become worse.